# Mapping db field to special type of POJO

Tags: java, sql, jpa, ebean

I have a database with FoodItems, each has data with protein in grams, energy in kcal etc. These are stored as just Float numbers.

I want to map these to a special POJO object called FoodData which just has the float number and then an Enum representing the unit like GRAMS, KCALS, MILLIGRAMS etc.

How can I do this?

This is what i have right now:

**FoodItem.java**

```
@Column(name = "energy_kcal") public Float energyKcal;
@Column(name = "energy_kj") public Float energyKj;
@Column(name = "carbohydrates_g") public Float carbohydrates;
@Column(name = "protein_g") public Float protein;
@Column(name = "fibre_g") public Float fibre;
@Column(name = "whole_grain_g") public Float wholeGrain;
@Column(name = "cholesterol_mg") public Float cholesterol;
@Column(name = "water_g") public Float water;
@Column(name = "alcohol_g") public Float alcohol;
@Column(name = "ash_g") public Float ash;
@Column(name = "waste_procent") public Float waste;
```

**FoodData.java**

```
public class FoodData {

    private float data;
    private Unit unit;

    public Enum Unit {
         GRAMS, KCAL, MILLIGRAMS
    }
}
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
@Column(name = "energy_kcal") public FoodData energyKcal = new FoodData(data_from_column, Unit.KCAL);
```

But that's not how you do it, how DO you do this?

Comment: have a look at http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#CriteriaBuilder39s_construct_

Comment: Thank you! I was more thinking in the lines of annotating your model classes and not the query way though...

Comment: Your "what I want to do" doesnt compile of course, and its not clear WHAT you want to do there.

Comment: @NeilStockton Yes sry about the static type there, made it more confusing. What I want to do is have float data in the database and map those to a POJO object that is essentially a pair of a float (the real db data) and an enum.

Comment: Look at using a JPA AttributeConverter perhaps? so FoodData is not an entity

Comment: That looks like just the thing I need, awesome. Thank you so much!